# Using repositories on frontend with paging

Tags: magento2, frontend, pagination, service-contract

I've created a CRUD module in the proper way, with service contracts (SC).
I'm using these SC in the backend with ui-components and everything.
This works nicely, but I want to use the repository's `getList` method in the frontend with paging and everything.
Basically I want to have a page that lists my custom entity instances and have them paginated. 
My repository interface contains (among others) the method

```
public function getList(\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria);
```

It looks very similar to the [block repository interface](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Cms/Api/BlockRepositoryInterface.php) and the implementation of the interface looks like the [block repository](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Cms/Model/BlockRepository.php).
I didn't find any example in the core that uses the repositories for frontend listing including paging. That would be enough to get me started.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use the searchCriteria but use the GET params to set the current page and page size of products to be shown.

```
$this->_searchCriteria
        ->setFilterGroups(null)
        ->setPageSize(50)
        ->setCurrentPage(1);
```

Obviously you can use the Filter Groups as well, and not set to null as my example shows, if you have a need for a complex query.

So maybe instead of hard coding setPageSize(50) it may look like setPageSize($_GET['max']).

I hope this helps.

Comment: this means I have to get myself the parameters from GET and apply them for each collection I'm displaying? is there a method for that? A block or something as it is for the paging block in the "collection" way of doing things?

Comment: I used that logic (above) in an admin route, and it seemed that this may be close enough to what you were asking. Also, I know when we were trying to complete the Magento 2 training there was a question about controllers and our solution had a sorting, and paging but we did not use the above code example.  We created a toolbar that had to do all the work ( as you said ).  I am not sure if we did the task properly, but I can forward you our code if you want to see if it may work for you.